# How to write and read the wxcheckbox entries to registry?

Tags: wxpython

I am developing a GUI using wxpython where i have the information to be entry in different formats say textctrl, spinctrl, checkbox etc. I could able to write all these entries to and from registry  except for checkbox. It would be great if anyone could tell me how would i do that?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "registry" ? The Windows Registry?

Comment: Yes...The windows registry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and write to the Windows Registry, the usual method is to use Python _winreg module. I would just bind EVT_CHECKBOX to a handler and then use the IsChecked() method to see if it is checked or not. Depending on what is returned, you would write either a 1 or a 0 (or a True/False) to the registry using the aforementioned module.

Here are a couple links on _winreg:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/20/pythons-_winreg-editing-the-windows-registry/